# Changing text in another form by clicking a button

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I've been trying to change the text of a textbox in Form1 by clicking a button (button1 in form2 is "STARTA") in Form2 and probably spent a good 2 hours now (I'm a programming-newbie!).
I have been searching around for similiar questions and found a bunch, but even after trying a lot of them I can't get it to work.

Form1[DESIGN]

[image]

Form2[DESIGN]

[image]

The method I'm trying right now is something I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704020/changing-a-labels-text-in-another-form-in-c)

In Form1 I wrote this:

```
public string STARTTID
{
    get
    {
        return this.textBox3.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        this.textBox3.Text = value;
    }
}
```

I know it doesn't quite make sense to get and set an empty textBox, but I've tried so many different solutions which I think should work, but the textBox's text just wont change when I click the button!
In form2, when button1 is clicked, I wrote this:

```
string TIDEN = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
Form1 first = new Form1();
first.STARTTID = TIDEN;
```

What I'm trying to do, is that I want the text in textBox3 in form1 to change to the current time when button1 in form2 is pressed.

Sorry if this post is a bit messy, it's my first and english isn't my strongest language.

Comment: Do you have an error or is it just not working?

Comment: Can you post some more complete code, for example I can't see where you are calling first.show() etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is you creating new `Form1` and update label on that one, not in the your initial form

```
    Form1 first = new Form1();
    first.STARTTID = TIDEN;
```

You don't need to create new form because you already created it. what you can do is parse the Form1 to Form2 when you create Form2 by using constructor which accept Form as parameter. or create property in Form2 for Form1 and set that when you creating Form2.

**Form1**

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
f2.Show();
```

**Form2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 form1;

    public Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.form1 = form1;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form1.STARTTID = "set by form2";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afarid I don't quite follow as my knowledge of parameters, constructors and "parse" is too limited, could you show me in code somewhat what I need to change?