# C# - Fill Listview in a different form - VS2015

Tags: c#, windows, forms, listview

I have 2 forms. Form 1 which shows a ListView and Form 2 a button called button1.
What I'm trying to do is when the button on form 2 is clicked. I want it to fill the Listview on form1.

The listview has 3 columns;
Flavour
Quantity
Sub-Total

When the button1 is pressed, it should show **Vanilla, 1, £1.00** in the listview on form1.

**I'm able to do this if the listview is on the same form as the button, but not if it's on different forms.**

Form1

```
public partial class form1: Form
{
    public form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Form2

```
public partial class form2: Form
{
    public form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem("Vanilla");
        lvi.SubItems.Add("1");
        lvi.SubItems.Add("£1.00");
        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried passing a reference of form1 to form2?

Comment: @Sylverac You mean this? Form2 form2 = new Form2();

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704020/changing-a-labels-text-in-another-form-in-c). It's talking about labels but it should still point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Create a reference of `form1` in `form2` like this:

```
class Program {
    static void Main() { 
        var form1 = new Form1();
        var form2 = new Form2(form1);
    }
}

public partial class Form1: Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void DoStuff(ListViewItem lvi) {
        // TODO: Stuff
    }
}

public partial class Form2: Form
{
    private Form1 _form1;

    public form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _form1 = form1;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem("Vanilla");
        lvi.SubItems.Add("1");
        lvi.SubItems.Add("£1.00");
        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);

        _form1.DoStuff(lvi);
    }
}
```

Comment: @imraanstack1 Can you be more specific? What is the problem?