# Send information from a textbox in one form to a label in another form? C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Evening, I'm currently doing a "Card game" which is a school project, and I want to be able to change each players name by pressing a "Change name" button which will bring up a second form which has two textboxes, when I fill these two textboxes out and press okay I want the two labels representing the names on the first form to change to the text typed in my second form..

This is what i've tried..

```
//form1
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Show();
}
```

Second form:

```
//form2
public string TheValue
{
    get { return textBox1.Text; }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

I understand that I should have something under `button1_Click()` in the second form, I just can't figure out what...

Comment: Check here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704020/changing-a-labels-text-in-another-form-in-c